# Creating an envelope from a template returning "UNSPECIFIED_ERROR"

Tags: javascript, node.js, docusignapi

When I try to create an envelope from a template I get a response of:

```
{ errorCode: 'UNSPECIFIED_ERROR',
  message: 'Non-static method requires a target.' }
```

Here's what I'm doing so far:

First I login, which returns

```
 { loginAccounts: 
   [ { name: '*****',
       accountId: '*****',
       baseUrl: 'https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/******',
       isDefault: 'true',
       userName: '***** ********',
       userId: '*******-*****-*****-*****-*********',
       email: '********@*******.com',
       siteDescription: '' } ] }
```

So then I take the baseUrl out of that response and I attempt to create the envelope.  I'm using the hapi framework and `async.waterfall` of the async library, so for anyone unfamiliar with either of these my use of the async library uses the `next` callback to call the next function which in this case would be to get the url for the iframe, and with our usage of the hapi framework `AppServer.Wreck` is roughy equivalent to `request`:

```
    function prepareEnvelope(baseUrl, next) {
        var createEntitlementTemplateId = "99C44F50-2C97-4074-896B-2454969CAEF7";
        var getEnvelopeUrl  = baseUrl + "/envelopes";
        var options = {
            headers: {
                "X-DocuSign-Authentication": JSON.stringify(authHeader),
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Content-Disposition": "form-data"
            },
            body : JSON.stringify({
                status: "sent",
                emailSubject: "Test email subject",
                emailBlurb: "My email blurb",
                templateId: createEntitlementTemplateId,
                templateRoles: [
                    {
                        email: "anemailaddress@gmail.com",
                        name: "Recipient Name",
                        roleName: "Signer1",
                        clientUserId: "1099", // TODO: replace with the user's id
                        tabs : {
                            textTabs : [
                                {
                                     tabLabel : "acct_nmbr",
                                     value : "123456"
                                },
                                {
                                    tabLabel : "hm_phn_nmbr",
                                    value : "8005882300"
                                },
                                {
                                    tabLabel : "nm",
                                    value : "Mr Foo Bar"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            })
        };

        console.log("--------> options: ", options); // REMOVE THIS ====

        AppServer.Wreck.post(getEnvelopeUrl, options, function(err, res, body) {
            console.log("Request Envelope Result: \r\n", JSON.parse(body));
            next(null, body, baseUrl);
        });
    }
```

And what I get back is:

```
 { errorCode: 'UNSPECIFIED_ERROR',
  message: 'Non-static method requires a target.' }
```

From a little googling it look like 'Non-static method requires a target.' is a C# error and doesn't really give me much indication of what part of my configuration object is wrong.

I've tried a simpler version of this call stripping out all of the tabs and clientUserId and I get the same response.

I created my template on the Docusign website and I haven't ruled out that something is set up incorrectly there.  I created a template, confirmed that Docusign noticed the named form fields, and created a 'placeholder' templateRole.

Here's the templateRole placeholder:
[image: placeholder templateRole]

Here's one of the named fields that I want to populate and corresponding data label:
[image: named form fields]

As a side note, I was able to get the basic vanilla example working without named fields nor using a template using the docusign node package just fine but I didn't see any way to use tabs with named form fields with the library and decided that I'd rather have more fine-grained control over what I'm doing anyway and so I opted for just hitting the APIs.

Surprisingly when I search SO for the errorCode and message I'm getting I could only find one post without a resolution :/

Of course any help will be greatly appreciated.  Please don't hesitate to let me know if you need any additional information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once I received feedback from Docusign that my api call had an empty body it didn't take but a couple minutes for me to realize that the issue was my options object containing a `body` property rather than a `payload` property, as is done in the hapi framework.

Comment: I love you dude! I too didn't have the body property and kept geting the annoying error. I am using the esign api and it worked after adding it. Thanks!!!